# Casting using type assertion in golang

Tags: go, type-assertion

I understood that casting is being implemented in go using type assertion.

I'm trying to cast an object which is an instance of a struct that implements an interface.

My Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Base interface {
    Merge(o Base)
}

type Impl struct {
    Names []string
}

func (i Impl) Merge (o Base) {
  other, _ := o.(Impl)
  i.Names = append(i.Names, other.Names...)
}

func main() {
    impl1 := &Impl{
        Names: []string{"name1"},
    }
    
    impl2 := &Impl{
        Names: []string{"name2"},
    }
    
    impl1.Merge(impl2)
    fmt.Println(impl1.Names)
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
[name1]
```

I expect the output to be:

```
[name1, name2]
```

Why this casting doesn't work? After debugging this it seems like that the `other` variable is empty.

Comment: The question has got nothing to do with type assertions or casting. You need to use a pointer receiver for `Merge` method. In your implementation, `Merge` receives a copy of the receiver and modifies it, so the copy in `main` is never modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a pointer method to modify the receiver's build.

```
func (i *Impl) Merge (o Base) {
  other, _ := o.(*Impl)
  i.Names = append(i.Names, other.Names...)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7NQQnfJ_G6A